# Excel VBA / Sheets.Add.Name Loop throws Error 9

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to Excel VBA and started to build a time tracking workbook for learning.
A part of that is a For-Loop which shall add one named worksheet for every month in a year:

```
Sub newyear()

Dim month(12) As String
Dim i As Integer

month(1) = "Januar"
month(2) = "Februar"
...
month(12) = "Dezember"

For i = 1 To 12
On Error Resume Next
Sheets.Add(Tabelle1).Name = month(i)
MsgBox Err.Number    <- this throws Error 9: "Subscript Out Of Range" after
                        every worksheet added during the loop
Next i

End Sub
```

During Runtime while the loop is adding worksheet after worksheet the MsgBox pops up after every single added sheet with Error 9: "Subscript Out Of Range".

I don't know why this is happening, started reading up quite a bit on the web  and still have no solution.. maybe I'm missing something basic, because I'm a beginner.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please mark as the solution if my code fits with you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you want to avoid having an error. You can probably make a longwinded code for that, but there no use for it. You can also try something shorter:

```
Sub newyear()

   Dim month(12) As String
   Dim i As Integer

   month(1) = "January"
   month(2) = "February"
   month(3) = "March"
   month(4) = "April"
   month(5) = "May"
   month(6) = "June"
   month(7) = "July"
   month(8) = "August"
   month(9) = "September"
   month(10) = "October"
   month(11) = "November"
   month(12) = "Dezember"

   On Error Resume Next
   For i = 1 To 12
       If Worksheets(month(i)) Is Nothing Then
           Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = month(i)
       End If
   Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah.. well that's the conclusion I also cam to: Why actually try to avoid the error?! But, you know, I thought when my code throws an error than obviously I coded something wrong, no? I thought the goal is to write clean code and naive me thought clean code shouldn't generate errors. Whatever thanks for the input :).

Comment: Sometimes an error is not a problem, but a feature :) In VBA, as in Excel, you can use errors to your benefit. It's a good shortcut for many cases.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the below code.

```
Sub newyear()
On Error Resume Next
Dim month(12) As String
Dim i As Integer
month(1) = "January"
month(2) = "February"
month(3) = "March"
month(4) = "April"
month(5) = "May"
month(6) = "June"
month(7) = "July"
month(8) = "August"
month(9) = "September"
month(10) = "October"
month(11) = "November"
month(12) = "Dezember"
Dim ws As Worksheet
For i = 1 To 12
    With ThisWorkbook
        If Worksheets(month(i)).Name <> month(i) Then
            Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
            ws.Name = month(i)
        End If
    End With
    If Err.Description <> "" Then
        Err.Clear
        'do what you want to do 
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Sadly after adding 'MsgBox = Err.Number' before 'Next i' to your code Error 9 ist still popping up after each added sheet :(.

Comment: @Fr4gFr0g, May i know why you adding Err.Number before Next i

Comment: @Fr4gFr0g, edited the above answer. Pls mark as solution if its correct.

Comment: Okay, so initially I wanted the loop to function correctly, even if sheets for some months already exist. When that's the case the loop adds an unnamed sheet for every existing one <- I wanted to detect this by checking for error like this `If Err.Description <> "" Then activesheet.delete` (pseudo code). The Problem is that the named sheets also get deleted because for every sheet added (even if it's not already existing) Error 9 pops up.. and sadly, with your solution this Error 9 still happens.

Comment: Well.. this just clears the Error. It still doesn't prevent it from happening in the first place.

Comment: so you don't want to create sheets if already exists. Correct? Pls see the edited code

Comment: Well, yes I do want to do that.. and I can easily ignore the error to get to my goal, as I already did actually. But I posted this question to get to know the background as to why Error 9 comes up in the first place. But judging by your answer and that of @IvanTokarev I just have to live with it. Thanks for your input anyways!